# How to detect framerate from video playing on video tag?

Tags: html

Is there any way I can detect via javascript what is the framerate from the video referenced in the video html5 tag?

I'm also looking for bitrate and codec information since html5 video player is codec agnostic.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The FPS is stored in the metadata of the `video` file's header.

Here is an implementation API of what you are looking for: https://github.com/X3TechnologyGroup/VideoFrame

http://jsfiddle.net/Ck6Zq/184/

Comment: From what I see of the doc, you actually have to specify the framerate

Comment: yeah, where can u find it in the metadata of the video again?