# How can I measure the actual framerate of video using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, performance-testing

Assume a video is playing in an HTML5 page using the `<video>` tag. How can I measure the actual framerate? I do not just want to read the framerate of the video file ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28532004/211327), but what the browser is able to manage in practice.

(I’m guessing it will be possible to hack something together involving `requestAnimationFrame`, but I vaguely worry that on some systems, video playback will be decoupled from the rest of the page, leading to an incorrect result; additionally I hope there might be a more direct metric.)

Answer (score 1):

You could try exploring [VideoPlaybackQuality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VideoPlaybackQuality), maybe the metrics it gives out can be useful to you. 
More specifically the [dropped frames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VideoPlaybackQuality/droppedVideoFrames) or [total frames presented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VideoPlaybackQuality/totalVideoFrames) values.

Maybe involving those results along with other options like `requestAnimationFrame`?

I'm not sure what your exact end-goal of your project is. For example *"How can I measure the actual framerate?"* I personally can interpret that as either:

**(1)** Speed of the video decoder **per frame** (for given video type).
 For example the decoding speed of each single frame @ 720p vs maybe 4K resolution.

**(2)** Number of frames dropped **per second**.
Where you minus the FPS number against the dropped frames to know how many were presented.

Here is a quick/basic example usage of [VideoPlaybackQuality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VideoPlaybackQuality):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video id="myvid" width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<br><br>
<text id="mytxt"> </text>

</body>

<script>

var mytxt = document.getElementById("mytxt");
var myvid = document.getElementById("myvid");

var fps = 30; //# use real FPS of input video
var vid_data; //# an Object for VideoPlaybackQuality 
var myInterval; //# to check Quaity statistics every second

var vidPaused = false;

myvid.addEventListener('play', onVidEvents);
myvid.addEventListener('pause', onVidEvents);
myvid.addEventListener('ended', onVidEvents);
 
function onVidEvents()
{
    if (event.type == "play")
    {
        vidPaused = false; 
        myInterval = setInterval(check_framesQuality, 1000); 
    }

    if (event.type == "seeked")
    { vid_data = myvid.getVideoPlaybackQuality(); update_text(); }

    if (event.type == "pause")
    { vidPaused = true; clearInterval(myInterval); }

    if (event.type == "ended")
    { clearInterval(myInterval); vidPaused = true;}
}

function check_framesQuality()
{
    if( vidPaused == false ) 
    { 
        vid_data = myvid.getVideoPlaybackQuality();
        update_text();
    }
}

function update_text()
{
    mytxt.innerText = "Total Decoded Frames : " + vid_data.totalVideoFrames 
    + "\n" + "Dropped Frames : " + vid_data.droppedVideoFrames
    + "\n" + "===================="
    + "\n" + "Video Time (secs) : " + Math.round( myvid.currentTime )
    + "\n" + "Expected Frames : " + Math.round( fps * myvid.currentTime  )
    
    //# received frames == ( expectedFrames - DroppedFrames )
    + "\n" + "Received Frames : " + ( Math.round( fps * myvid.currentTime) - vid_data.droppedVideoFrames)

}

</script>
</html>
```